# Xcode cannot find ComposeUIViewController in a kotlin multi platform project

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin multi-platform project set up with Jetpack Compose. I have created a `Base Composable` class as follows:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ClipRApp() {
  MaterialTheme(
    typography = ClipRTypography
  ) {
    SplashScreen()
  }
}
```

This works fine inside Android. However, when I try to call the same `Composable` to run in iOS by creating a `ComposeUIViewController` inside a file named `IosMainApp.kt` in the `iosMain/kotlin/<package_name>/` path:

```kotlin
fun MainViewController() = ComposeUIViewController {
  ClipRApp()
}
```

After modifying my `xcworkspace` file to use my `ComposeUIViewController`, I encountered a `Cannot find 'IosMainAppKt' in scope` error as shown in the following image:

[image]

Going through similar questions and answers, I ran `pod install` and tried building with `⌘ + B` but it didn't help. How do I resolve this issue?

I am using compose version `1.4.0`

Comment: your shared build failed, go to report navigator tab and look for KMM logs to find out the reason